# Why can't ubuntu install detect my other drives?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, ssd

I was going install 14.04 on my desktop but because of the bad word rendering during the installation and searched up, found out using the newest ubuntu won't have such problem so I downloaded yesterday I believe it's 16.10 or close haha.  Anyways, during the installation process word rendering is perfect that I can see all words during the installation setup BUT I clicked install window 7 alongside, it asked me to choose HDD for the installation.  Somehow it only detects my 2TB HDD which doesn't even have windows OS in it.  I have one SSD (with windows OS), one 1TB and one 2TB.  I want it to detect my SSD so I can install it in my SSD too which of course would run faster.

Anyone know the reason why it's not seeing my other two HDD?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided zero information about your setup, it would be impossible to know the cause.

However, a workaround would be to just disconnect the SATA cable from your HDD, leaving only the SSD connected for the installation.

Afterwards, you could connect your HDD again.

Comment: what kind of setup info should I get?
And that's a nice idea for taking out the cables :D